# Some scholars says that you cannot make the plural and feminine form of word Allah from arabic linguistic perspective

Tags: history, arabic

Is it possible from arabic linguistic perspective to make the plural and feminine form of word الله? for example اللهون plural form of word الله and اللت feminine form of word الله because in Arabic, the regular way of making a plural for a masculine noun is adding the suffix -ūn[a] (for the nominative) at the end and To make a masculine word feminine usually a ة (h/t) is added to the end of the word so when you add ون to الله it becomes اللهون plural form of الله and when you add ت or ة to the end of the word then it becomes feminine for example when we add ت to الله it becomes اللت feminine form of word الله so when it is possible to make plural and feminine forms of word الله so why some scholars says الله is the unique word which you cannot make plural or feminine form from arabic linguistic perspective?

Comment: Arabic linguistics are not the topic of this site (see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). There are some examples like: امرآة which has neither plural nor masculine and ابل which is a plural which does not have a singular. However in most cases these existed once in a time, but are no more in use. Like نساء which is a plural and the only known and used singular for it is امرآة, but it had singulars such نسأة and نسيئة both are no more in use. Beside this there are words or nouns in Arabic that are both plural and singular like فلك.